# How can i convert a string to all possible charset?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I was wondering how should i do to convert a string in Arabic to all possible charset supported by java
 is it possible ?
I searched in the net and i found that java supports this [set of encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) and what i would do is like:

```
      enter the string : hello <-- in arabic
            charset utf 8 ==> XXXXX  <---- this is the converted string for utf 8
            charset iso8859_1 ==> XXXXX  <----  this is the converted string for iso8859_1
```

after the answer of VYTAS i made this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    SortedMap<String, Charset> availableCharsets = Charset.availableCharsets();
    Set<String> keySet = availableCharsets.keySet();
    for (String key : keySet) {
        try {
        System.out.println(new String(availableCharsets.get(key).encode("عباس").array(), availableCharsets.get(key)) );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the output is only squares and '?' and sometimes the Arabic String, is what i have done correct ? because I m expecting something like in this [website](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=fr) using the word :'عباس'.

thanks

Comment: will it work in case of arabic `byte[] charset = string.getBytes("IBM420");` ?

Comment: A String doesn't have a charset.  Only a sequence of bytes (a byte array, an InputStream, etc.) has a charset.  (Technically all Java Strings do have the same charset, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: Encoded strings are bytes (See previous comment) and your terminal or console on recognises one type of encoding at any one time. So you really need to write your test string to separate files

Comment: Besides the nonsensical idea of “encoding” a `String` into a `String`, it’s a waste of resources to loop over the keys of a `Map` to perform `get` on the same `Map` with each key (not to speak about doing the lookup even twice per key. If you need the key and value, you can loop over `Map.entrySet()`, but since you don’t use the keys at all (besides the obsolete lookup), you can simply loop over the values: `for(Charset cs: availableCharsets.values()) { … }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a String in Arabic, you can do this:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(str);
```

where 'UTF-8' is canonical name of the charset for java.nio API, 
and 'str' is your String in Arabic.